# Which of phantomjs or webdriver would be easier/more-appropriate for scraping my linkedin account?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

I have a personal need to scrape/automate-access-to my linkedin account (copy my contacts, etc), and obviously the site is too ajaxy to just use wget, urllib, etc.

I *cannot* use the LinkedIn API, as it happens to restrict some use cases I'm interested in.

I am proficient in Python and Javascript. I've used webdriver in the past for small scraping projects, but it was long ago enough that there's probably a similar overhead in re-learning it vs learning phantomjs.

I am not planning to run any kind of high-volume cluster-based scraping operation, this is all going to be running on my local machine at some appropriate rate limit so as not to piss off linkedin. It's mostly just for personal convenience, automation, etc.

I've heard good things about phantomjs, but I'd like to understand what if any advantage it has over webdriver (or vice versa). I guess phantomjs is "headless", meaning it doesn't actually have to run a browser, which I guess makes it easier to write command line scripts or consume fewer resources or some other property that I would love to have explained to me!

I can appreciate the argument that webscraping programs should be javascript, since that's more of a browser-native language, but would love to hear if that's a primary reason why people are using phantomjs (or one of its cousins)

Comment: Just let you know, I am using headless selenium..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used both Selenium and Phantom/Casper in scraping jobs, and also used both in functional testing jobs. If I was going to do what you describe I would choose CasperJS. I would choose CasperJS over PhantomJS because:

- Easier to describe the flow of steps. (You have to deal with all the async callbacks when using PhantomJS directly.)
- SlimerJS can be swapped in to have it use Gecko (i.e. Firefox), with no additional effort. (I don't think this will matter with LinkedIn, but PhantomJS 1.9.x is based on a fairly old WebKit, so when sites use newer HTML5 features it can sometimes fail.)

Reasons to choose CasperJS over Selenium:

- The flow of steps is quite easy to describe in CasperJS.
- Selenium feels more like hard work. This might be because PHP is my preferred glue language, and since Selenium 2.0, PHP has been treated as an outsider. But also it has the philosophy of only allowing actions that a user could do in the browser with keyboard and mouse. This is sometimes not flexible enough.
- Selenium breaks each time Firefox gets updated, and I have to install the latest version. Irritating. (PhantomJS and SlimerJS have their browser internally, so are cleanly independent of system updates to your desktop browser.)

As you are proficient in both Python and JavaScript, I would say none of the above are killer reasons. It doesn't really matter which you choose, the effort is going to be roughly the same.

Comment: thanks for the great answer, Darren, and also for explaining the value of CasperJS (which had also been recommended to me but I didn't understand what it provided)